# Docker-compose build laravel - stuck on RUN npm run prod

Tags: php, laravel, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have laravel application. I try to build it with docker. I use `docker-compose -f docker-compose_Nginx.yml build --no-cache`. But it always stuck on `RUN npm run prod`.

```
PS C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Studia\Kursy\Kurs PHP-Laravel ZZ\shop-yt>  docker-compose -f docker-compose_Nginx.yml build --no-cache
2023/07/30 17:01:45 http2: server: error reading preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been closed
[+] Building 219.3s (20/23)
 => => naming to docker.io/library/shop-yt-nginx                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [laravel stage-0  3/10] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s 
 => [laravel stage-0  4/10] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                               0.2s 
 => [laravel stage-0  5/10] COPY --from=composer:2.5.8 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
 => [laravel stage-0  6/10] RUN npm install -g n && n 18.16.1                                                                                                                                                                     12.6s 
 => [laravel stage-0  7/10] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                                        5.6s 
 => [laravel stage-0  8/10] RUN npm run prod
```

**`Dockerfile_Laravel`**

```
FROM php:8.2

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . .
COPY --from=composer:2.5.8 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN npm install -g n && n 18.16.1
RUN npm install
RUN npm run prod

RUN composer install --no-interaction --no-progress

RUN cd public && ln -sf ../storage/app/public/ storage

ENV PORT=9000
ENTRYPOINT ["docker/nginx/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**`Dockerfile_Nginx`**

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY docker/nginx/vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

ENV PORT=80
```

**`docker-compose_Nginx.yml`**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    laravel:
        container_name: shop-yt-app-n
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_Laravel
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        volumes:
            - shop-yt-volume:/var/www/html/storage
        networks:
            - shop-yt-network

    nginx:
      container_name: shop-yt-nginx
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile_Nginx
      ports:
        - 80:80
      networks:
        - shop-yt-network

    database:
        container_name: shop-yt-db
        image: mariadb:latest
        ports:
            - ${DB_PORT}:3306
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - shop-yt-db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - shop-yt-network

volumes:
    shop-yt-volume:
        driver: local
    shop-yt-db-volume:
        driver: local

networks:
    shop-yt-network:
        driver: bridge
```

**`entrypoint.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash

php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear

php artisan serve --port=$PORT --host=0.0.0.0
```

**`entrypoint.sh`**

```
upstream laravel {
    server laravel:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://laravel;
    }
}
```

Comment: RUN npm run prod this command will run server so will not go further while server is running

Comment: @Ruslan you may be confused but that is not true, if the user has `Larave mix`, running `npm run prod` will build and compress assets, but not start a server to serve them. If the user has `Vite`, running `npm run build` will build and compress assets, but not start a server to serve them

Comment: Author, could you try running `npm run prod -vvv`? And, as I said on your previous question, I strongly recommend you use `Laravel Sail`

Comment: `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain` might also help capturing the information from `-vvv` which you then should [edit] into the question.

Comment: @matiaslauriti thank you, its works for me. Can you tell why this command works only with `-vvv`?
I know about laravel sail, but for some reason I don't want to implement it in my current project. But I think in the next project I will use it :D

Comment: @janullo789 `-vvv` only gives you information back, it is a "verbose level 3" (that is why it is 3 `v`s). Maybe it was processing for you but because you did not see output you thought it was not working? Did you leave it run for a long time before adding `-vvv`?